# Count frequency of text in list in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I’m new to python / pandas but have a question which I’ll ask logically to help me learn

I have a dataframe called parties with the following data

```
(index)    name                  invitees
0            birthday party     [mike, peter]
1            Retirement          [peter]
2            office opening     [simon, mike, peter]
```

I’d like to be able to create a dictionary which will show the distinct names from the invitees column along with frequency e.g. something like this

```
mike: 2, peter: 3, simon: 1
```

I’ve tried to find something similar on here but I’m not too sure of the right terminology to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks a lot

Comment: You are probably looking for something along the lines of [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.Counter) from collections and [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from itertools to solve your problem:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

df2= pd.DataFrame({
    'name':["blah", "blah-blah", "waka-waka"],
    'invites':[['mike', 'peter'], ['peter', 'mike'], ['waka', 'peter', 'simon']]
})
Counter([elem for elem in chain.from_iterable(df2['invites'].values)])
```

> `Counter({'mike': 2, 'peter': 3, 'simon': 1, 'waka': 1})`

Answer (score 0):

Collect names from data frame and then use Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

# setup test data
data = {'invitees': [['mike', 'peter'], ['peter'], ['simon', 'mike', 'peter']]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# select data series
names_lists = data['invitees']

# collect names
all_names = []
for item in names_lists:
    for name in item:
        all_names.append(name)

# count occurrence
summary = Counter(all_names)
```

Output:

```
{'peter': 3, 'mike': 2, 'simon': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

invitees = [["mike", "peter"],["peter"],["simon", "mike", "peter"]]
name = ["birthday party","Retirement","office opening"]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data={"name":name,"invitees":invitees})

all_invitees = []
for i,row in new_df.iterrows():
    invitees.extend(row[1])

invitees_count = dict(Counter(all_invities))
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun

```
df['invitees'].apply(pd.Series).unstack().reset_index(name='n').drop('level_1', axis=1).dropna().groupby('n').count().to_dict()['level_0']
```

---

```
{'mike': 2, 'peter': 3, 'simon': 1}
```